# Cannot set any value LocalDateTime in Entity of Spring Boot Example

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I have a problem to set LocalDateTime.now to the entity of Spring Boot Example

Here is the entity shown below

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARK")
public class ParkEntity extends BaseEntity {

   ...

   @Column(name = "CHECK_IN")
   private LocalDateTime checkIn;


   ....
}
```

Here is the BaseEntity shown below

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "CREATED_USER")
    protected String createdUser;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_AT")
    protected LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_USER")
    protected String updatedUser;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_AT")
    protected LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        this.updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

...
}
```

Here is the method shown below

```
private Park parkMethod(....) {
        ParkEntity parkEntity = ....
        parkEntity.setCheckIn(LocalDateTime.now());
        ParkEntity savedPark = parkRepository.save(parkEntity);
        return parkEntityToParkMapper.map(savedPark);
}
```

I have also other `entities` extending from `BaseEntity`.

I get `null` value in `checkIn` of `savedPark` . I have to manually set the LocalDateTime.now() instead of using `@Builder.Default`

How can I do that?

Comment: By the way, `LocalDateTime` is the wrong data type to record a moment. For a specific point on the timeline, use `Instant`. To present to user, `ZonedDateTime`. I cannot imagine a case where calling `LocalDateTime.now` would be a smart move.

Comment: @BasilBourque I have also `@PrePersist` method in BaseEntity and that's why I cannot use it in ParkEntity. How can I implement it?

Comment: @BasilBourque I still couldn't fix the issue.

Comment: If you could enable logging of SQL queries and include the `INSERT` statement here, it could help find the root cause of your issue.